# Search dropdown instead of multiselect

Tags: magento-1.9, advanced-search

Using the standard advanced search block I am getting a Multiselect box instead of a dropdown. The attribute under 'Catalog Input Type for Store Owner' is set to 'Dropdown'... how can I fix this?

Comment: Which search field exactly? There are no multiselect drop downs I'm standard HTML. So if Magento needs multiple selections, a list is the only option. And a single select drop down is just a list with size=1

Comment: @Alex It is a <select multiple> list and I just want it to be a standard <select> dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208342/magento-change-attribute-select-to-dropdown-list-in-adv-search) on stackoverflow, so am posting here in case others are looking.

You have to edit the Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form stored in /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Advanced/Form.php

Then I commented out this line:

```
//$extra = 'multiple="multiple" size="4"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the .phtml template which renders the search function.